# How can I pass a variable into this function (in this instance)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display any post (firebase document) that contains a specific "postCreator" value. I have the query set up and working - the problem is trying to get them to actually show.

Just for clarification, if postCreator is "zbakaaa" then all documents with "zbakaaa" as its postCreator value in Firebase should show on the app.

When I run code like this, the app works properly - but only for that specific user ID. I am trying to get the code to run so that I can somehow set "userId" to post.postCreator, so when a user presses on the button to open this sheet, the post.postCreator is passed into the UserViewModel (class that following code is in) and then set to userId.

```
init() {
        getUserPosts()
    }
    
    func getUserPosts() {
        let userId = "rgOOOwD2cNdayJodbMgGGy9l9pB3"
        ref.collection("Posts").whereField("postCreator", isEqualTo: userId).addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in...
```

I have tried something like this (which I have working in an unrelated application), but this just throws errors.

```
var post: PostModel? {
        didSet{
            if let post = self.post {
                getUserPosts(userId: post.postCreator)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my program code for reference:

**PostModel**

```
struct PostModel : Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var pic: String
    var likes: Int64
    var time: Date
    var likedBy: [String]
    var user: UserModel
    var postCreator: String
    
}
```

**Button pressed to open this sheet (where postCreator should be put in?)**

```
var post : PostModel
@State private var showingUserProfile = false
...

Button(action: {
                    showingUserProfile = true
                }){
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: post.user.pic)!)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                }   
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingUserProfile)
                {
                    UserView(post:post)
                }
```

**UserViewModel Class**

```
class UserViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var posts : [PostModel] = []
    @Published var noPosts = false
    @Published var newPost = false
    @Published var updateId = ""
    
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    init() {
        getUserPosts()
    }
    
    func getUserPosts() {
        let userId = "rgOOOwD2cNdayJodbMgGGy9l9pB3"
        ref.collection("Posts").whereField("postCreator", isEqualTo: userId).addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            guard let docs = snap else{
                self.noPosts = true
                return
            }

...
```

Comment: Move `var post` into `UserViewModel`.

Comment: Just by adding var post I get 'Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties' and ''self' used in method call 'getUserPosts' before all stored properties are initialized'. Plus, (maybe I'm wrong) but shouldn't there be some way to pass postCreator in when I press the button to open the sheet? Because even if adding var post worked, I'm not sure that it could actually contain the postid without actually passing it in on a button press

Comment: Where is the code for `UserView` ? Ask yourself, is it a better user experience to fetch the posts for a postCreator then show the Action sheet, or is it better to show the action sheet, and in that view, fetch all the posts for a given postCreator.

Comment: UserView is where the button to open the sheet is. How would I show the sheet, and then fetch those posts in the view? That does sound significantly more efficient but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Rethought how I wanted to design this structure - came up with passing a variable, but now I'm facing errors with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052286/self-used-in-method-call-getuserposts-before-all-stored-properties-are-initi

Comment: I see that linked queston was deleted so probably best to remove your comment since it's not longer applicable.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you having difficulty retrieving data from Firestore or are you having trouble displaying it? Or.. something else entirely? Please update and clarify the question - it's probably answerable but we need to understand what's being asked and what the specific issue is.

Comment: Data is being retrieved from Firestore. The issue is getting userId (whether it be a value from Firestore, or a set string like "jdaIsbaOkgajI") to pass into the view model so I can use it in a query, or anywhere

Comment: In the question, it appears you *know* the user uid you are querying for - `.whereField("postCreator", isEqualTo: userId)` so what else is needed? e.g.  If you know you wants posts from a user with `uid_0`, you know that info. Is there something else? Can't you just pass the uid string - in this case `uid_0`?